# Are arrow functions optimized like named functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, arrow-functions

I was watching a NodeJS Interactive talk and the guy speaking was saying how anonymous functions were bad one of the reasons being that if they have no name, the VM cannot optimize the function based on how frequently it's used because its nameless.

So if a function with a name is called

`random.Async('Blah', function randomFunc() {});`

`randomFunc` can be optimized as where a function like:

`random.Async('Blah', function(cb) {});`

This will not be optimized because it's anonymous, nameless.

So I was wondering if arrow functions would do the same thing because I don't think you can name arrow functions.

Will

`random.Async('Blah', (cb) => {});` be optimized?

Edit: Looking for link to the talk where the guy mentions this, will report back. (This talk was from a while ago and its just something I remembered from it)

Edit Found the video: https://youtu.be/_0W_822Dijg?t=299

Comment: "how anonymous functions were bad one of the reasons being that if they have no name, the VM cannot optimize the function based on how frequent its used because its nameless." --- this needs a proper confirmation, since it sounds just wrong. Names exists purely for developers, VM is free to change it to whatever it likes.

Comment: `(cb) => {})` It is already optimized. what do you want to optimize with it?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy what do you mean by "is already optimized"?

Comment: Could you put up a link to the talk?

Comment: @zerkms It is a concise version of normal anonymous function. And performance wise both is gonna be the same. So I was wondering what OP is expecting above this.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy "And performance wise both is gonna be the same." --- you're putting too many assumptions in this phrase. In general nothing guarantees the performance to be the same (since they behave differently and have different properties). And even more - in some scenarios the fat arrow is **MUCH** slower (as of ~39x slower for firefox)

Comment: @zerkms—but that may just be early implementations, e.g. *forEach* was initially much slower than a *for* loop, but not now.

Comment: @zerkms oh. I am not aware of that until now. Then that may be because of auto binding of `this` value from the lexical scope.

Comment: @RobG and that is my point ("In general nothing guarantees the performance to be the same"): there is no absolute value for "performance" (not even sure what people mean when say "optimisation" in this thread - since VMs use the term for something very specific). It would vary on thousands of different nuances.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy My main wonder was because it was nameless (assuming what the guy in the talk was talking about how nameless functions are not optimized over ones that are named) I  was wondering if the fat arrow versions would never be optimized based on their usage

Comment: I added the video where I heard this from to the main post

Comment: @mrmcgreg its in the original post now

Comment: What other type of arrow functions are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, Not entirely certain that these are the pattern comparisons discussed at linked video presentation.

At 10000 iterations, named function appears to complete fastest at V8 implementation at chromium. `Arrow function` appeared to return results in less time than  anonymous function.

At 100000 iterations anonymous function completed in briefest time; `64.51ms` less than named function, while arrow function took `4902.01ms` more time to complete than named function.

```js
    var len = Array.from({
      length: 100000
    })

     // named function
    function _named() {

      console.profile("named function");
      console.time("named function");

      function resolver(resolve, reject) {
        resolve("named function")
      }

      function done(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }

      function complete() {
        console.timeEnd("named function");
        console.profileEnd();
        return "named function complete"
      }

      function callback() {
        return new Promise(resolver).then(done)
      }

      return Promise.all(len.map(callback)).then(complete);
    }

     // anonymous function
    function _anonymous() {
      console.profile("anonymous function");
      console.time("anonymous function");

      return Promise.all(len.map(function() {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              resolve("anonymous function")
            })
            .then(function(data) {
              console.log(data)
            })
        }))
        .then(function() {
          console.timeEnd("anonymous function");
          console.profileEnd();
          return "anonymous function complete"
        })
    }

     // arrow function
    function _arrow() {
      console.profile("arrow function");
      console.time("arrow function");

      return Promise.all(len.map(() => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
              resolve("arrow function")
            )
            .then((data) => {
              console.log(data)
            })
        }))
        .then(() => {
          console.timeEnd("arrow function");
          console.profileEnd();
          return "arrow function complete"
        })
    }

    _named().then(_anonymous).then(_arrow)
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oj87s38t/

Answer (score 1):

I believe what Matteo was referring to were functions that are called very few times (e.g. a callback that is only called once) and the v8 optimizations have nothing to do with whether the function is actually anonymous or not.

Also if you continue to watch, he mentions using a module called `reusify` that basically provides a pool of functions. By using this, it means you can get a function from the pool that may already be optimized, meaning it *could* execute faster than a typical one-time use callback. However not all use cases may be able to use something like this.