# What is the fastest way in ES7 to perform a merge of an object of object of string?

Tags: javascript, merge, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have an object that contains object that contains string.

```
  const userKeyframes = {
    from: {
      opacity: 1,
    },
    '40%': {
      transform: 'skew(20deg)',
      opacity: 1,
    },
    '80%': {
      transform: 'skew(-5deg)',
      opacity: 1,
    },
    to: {
      transform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) skew(10deg)',
      opacity: 0,
    },
  };
```

I use to do like this with ImmutableJS :

```
  const merge = fromJS(make(options)).mergeDeep(userKeyframes);
```

I have tried this (https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KiVy6f5eWDb44W4dXtE) but didn't worked :

```
  const merge = make(options);
  Object.keys(userKeyframes).forEach((key) => {
    Object.assign(merge[key], userKeyframes[key]);
  });
```

I don't think I wan't to keep immutableJS only for this.

What is the fastest way in ES7 to perform a merge of two of them without any third party library ?

Comment: Looks more like a return statement, than an object.

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficiant"? Note, arrow functions are not necessarily more efficient than `function(){}`, see [Are fat-arrow functions optimized like named functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732782/are-fat-arrow-functions-optimized-like-named-functions/36733881?s=1|2.3089#36733881)

Comment: By fastest, I mean that the algorithm doesn't need to be able to perform a deepMerge

Comment: @BigDong It seems like you already found the solution with your loop and `Object.assign`

Comment: I am not I am still trying to write it https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KiVy6f5eWDb44W4dXtE

Comment: _"but didn't worked"_  Can you describe "didn't worked", and create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you assume `merge[key]` exists for all keys, but obviously this is not guaranteed. So `Object.assign(merge[key], .......)` might have the first argument as `undefined`, which does not yield the desired effect (but an error).

Instead, create a new object for the first argument, and assign the result to `merge[key]`:

```
Object.keys(userKeyframes).forEach((key) => {
    merge[key] = Object.assign({}, userKeyframes[key]);
});
```

However, the above will overwrite whatever is in `merge[key]` before the assignment happens. There are two alternatives you could use to deal with this differently:

You could perform the assignment only when `merge[key]` does not yet exist, so that you only assign `userKeyframes[key]` in that case:

```
Object.keys(userKeyframes).forEach((key) => {
    if (!(key in merge)) {
        merge[key] = Object.assign({}, userKeyframes[key]);
    }
});
```

Or, alternatively, you may want to truly merge the two objects when both already exist, meaning you want to have all the properties from `userKeyframes[key]`, but also keep any other properties that were already in `merge[key]` which would get destroyed by the first solution.

In that case, provide both `merge[key]` and `userKeyframes[key]` as 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> arguments to `Object.assign`, given that `undefined` values in all but the first argument do not pose a problem:

```
Object.keys(userKeyframes).forEach((key) => {
    merge[key] = Object.assign({}, merge[key], userKeyframes[key]);
});
```

In this last piece of code, when `merge[key]` already had a value, its properties that do not occur in `userKeyframes[key]` will stay, and those that *do*, get overwritten with those from `userKeyframes[key]`, as stated in the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Description):

> Later sources' properties will ... overwrite earlier ones.

Comment: I like the last option but if the key is present in both, the way you have written it will make the application value override the user value which is not what I want.

Comment: The last option will not override what is already in the *merge* object. It will merely reassign what was already there, because of the last argument of `Object.assign`: the last argument will override any of the previous arguments. Admittedly, if for the same key the keyframes object had more properties in the object assigned to the same key, those will be copied next to the existing properties of `merge`.

Comment: So swapping to `merge[key] = Object.assign({}, merge[key], userKeyframes[key]);` will produce the expected result.

Comment: If the entry in the `userKeyframes` object should have precedence, then indeed put it last.