# Are Arrow Functions faster than bind method to pass this param

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I've been experimenting with ES6 for a while now and I have a question about the performance of the method `.bind(this)` compared to new arrow functions.

I would like to know if there are any performance improvement on using `.bind(this)` to traditional functions or if is better to user arrow functions and why.

I made the following test but I'm not sure why I'm getting different values each time I execute the test.

```js
function useBind() {
    if(this && this.i) {
        console.log(this.i);
    }
}

const noBind = () => {
    if(this && this.i) {
        console.log(this.i);
    }
}

function goFat() {
    this.i = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        noBind();
    }
}

function goTraditional() {
    this.i = 20;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        useBind.bind(this)();
    }

}

function race() {
  var start = performance.now();
  goTraditional();
  console.log('Traditional elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));
  start = performance.now();
  goFat()
  console.log('Fat elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));

  start = performance.now();
  goTraditional();
  console.log('Traditional elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));
  start = performance.now();
  goFat()
  console.log('Fat elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));

  start = performance.now();
  goTraditional();
  console.log('Traditional elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));
  start = performance.now();
  goFat()
  console.log('Fat elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));
  console.log('------');
}
```

Sorry if this questions is duplicated or there are other similar topics but I cannot found a concrete answer until now.

Comment: `useBind.bind(this); useBind();` - that's not how `bind` works anyway.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do that is so performance critical?

Comment: Do you care about the performance of the call or the performance of creating the function object?

Comment: `useBind.bind(this);` need to be called BEFORE loop, in other words you have written artificial situation with performance leaks

Comment: I guess arrow functions are faster for you... less typing...

Comment: @jalamprea See [Are arrow functions optimized like named functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732782/are-arrow-functions-optimized-like-named-functions/)

Comment: I'm learning about the usage of bind and arrow functions for that reason my tests and the perfomance leak, but It's amazing to learn from you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get varying results because your run-time is dominated by the calls to `console.log()`. If you do something as intensive as `console.log()` in the inner loops, the way you call them is not going to impact your run-time.

In general you shouldn't care about micro-optimizations until you know you need it. Use the style that fits the situation. If you can use arrow-functions, use them. They avoid the creation of a new function object as opposed to `bind`.

Your test would have to be rewritten `useBind.bind(this)()` if you want to actually call the bound function (instead of  `useBind.bind(this); useBind()`). If you care about performance, you would do the binding outside of the loop. Unless you want to measure the impact of creating the bound function too.